# B2C custom policy : The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I try to create an orchestration step that just set the value of a claim. I used the starter pack *scenarios/phone-number-passwordless/Phone_Email_Base.xml* as a sample with the **DoesStrongAuthEmailExist** TechnicalProfile So basicaly I have a Claim :

```xml
     <ClaimType Id="isThisAvailable">
        <DisplayName>Determines if something is available in an environment</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
```

A claim transformation method :

```xml
     <ClaimsTransformation Id="SetThisIsAvailableClaim" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="false" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isThisAvailable" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

A claim provider with TechnicalProfile :

```xml
   <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Availability check</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="CheckIfThisIsAvailable">
          <DisplayName>Test</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetThisIsAvailableClaim" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isThisAvailable" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

And the orchestration step which is the first of the journey :

```xml
       <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TEST-CheckIfThisIsAvailable" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CheckIfThisIsAvailable" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

But when I call the user journey, I get this error in Dialog Insight :
**The method or operation is not implemented**

Note that I also tested putting the transformation in the OutputClaimsTransformations section of my TechnicalProfile without any success.

Here are the last log lines from dialog insight showing that it happens in step 1 :

> {
> "Kind": "Action",
> "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.MoveFirstOrchestrationStepHandler"
> },   {
> "Kind": "HandlerResult",
> "Content": {
> "Result": true,
> "Statebag": {
> "ORCH_CS": {
> "c": "2022-11-11T21:17:53.9870141Z",
> "k": "ORCH_CS",
> "v": "1",
> "p": true
> }
> }
> }   },   {
> "Kind": "Action",
> "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.InvokeValidationProfileDirectHandler"
> },   {
> "Kind": "FatalException",
> "Content": {
> "Time": "9:17 PM",
> "Exception": {
> "Kind": "Handled",
> "HResult": "80004001",
> "Message": "The method or operation is not implemented.",
> "Data": {}
> }
> }   } ]

**EDIT**

I found out that it works when using the authorize enpoint, but I get the error when I use the token endpoint.

To make things perectly clear, the only step in the actual orchestration  is to get a ROPC token, for tests in dev environments. That works fine on a call to the token endpoint.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ResourceOwnerFlow" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2">
          <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn - ROPC</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Settings:Tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Settings:Tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
            <Item Key="grant_type">password</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="logonIdentifier" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Password}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{Settings:ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="{Settings:IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

But as soon as I try to add an orchestration step before like this, I get an error

```xml
<UserJourney Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials">
      <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="TEST-CheckIfThisIsAvailable" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="CheckIfThisIsAvailable" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ResourceOwnerFlow" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: I believe the issue arises because the isThisAvailable claim type is a boolean, while the CreateStringClaim method operates on string claims. What happens when you set isThisAvailable's datatype to string?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the type is "string", I changed it in the question too.

Comment: Wow this is exactly the issue I just ran into doing almost the exact same thing.  Did you ever workaround it or figure out what the issue is?  Here's what I posted to MS Q+A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1304864/error-trying-to-default-claims-in-custom-policy-du

Answer (score 0):

If you are just setting the claim to a specific value, you could use

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isThisAvailable" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

Comment: the problem remains as I still can't call the first TechnicalProfile. I also tried changing the protocol back to "None" (since there's no more transformation involved in your sample) and get the message that the protocol "None" is not supported. I also noted that my problem does not occur on a call to the authorize endpoint, only to the token endpoint. I will edit the question